# If $ T(f(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}} dt $, what is $T(T(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Given $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function define
$$ T(f(x)) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x \dfrac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}} dt .$$
Show that
$$ T(T(f(x))) = \int_0^x f(t) dt. $$

Comment: Not a good idea to use an all-LaTeX title.

Comment: Why give the possibility if it shouldn't be done?

Comment: @user92797, your argument is also good for a assassin. Anyway, did you tried something?

Comment: Plug it in and switch the orders. You should say what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your definition - this may require some care to get the integration variables right, but I get

$$T(T(f(x)) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^x dt \, (x-t)^{-1/2} \, \int_0^t dt' \, (t-t')^{-1/2} \, f(t')$$

Now reverse the order of integration.  This must also be done carefully - a graph helps here.  But reversing isolates all of the square roots to the inner integral:

$$T(T(f(x)) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^x dt' \, f(t') \, \int_{t'}^x dt \, (x-t)^{-1/2} (t-t')^{-1/2}$$

You need to show that the inner integral is equal to $\pi$.  This may be done with some smart substitution and knowing that

$$\int_0^1 dv \, v^{-1/2} (1-v)^{-1/2} = \pi$$

You may recognize the last integral as one from the Gamma function.